# react-native fetch with authorization header sometime return 401

Tags: laravel, react-native, laravel-5

I'm facing some issue whereby I sometime will get status code 401 (Unauthorised) from my phone. I'm trying to access to an API from my computer localhost (192.168.0.7).

I've a screen, when I click on a button it will navigate to a page and it will request data through API. And when I go back and navigate to same page again, it sometime will return me code 401.

So if I repeat the same step (navigate and go back) let's say 10 times. I'm getting Unauthorised like 5-7 times.

Below are my code

```
export function getMyCarpool(param,token) {
    return dispatch => {   
        var requestUrl = _api + 'GetMyProduct?' + param;
        fetch(requestUrl, {
            method: "get",
            headers: new Headers({
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            })
        })
        .then((request) => {
            console.log(request);
            if(request.status == 200)
                return request.json();
            else if(request.status == 401) {
                //dispatch(logout());    
                throw new Error('Unauthorized access.');
            }
            else 
                throw new Error('Failed to request, please try again.');
        })
        .then((response) => {
            var message = response.message;
            if(response.success == 'true') 
                dispatch({ message, type: GET_MY_PRODUCT_SUCCESS });
            else
                dispatch({ message, type: GET_MY_PRODUCT_FAILED });
        })
        .catch(error => { 
            var message = error.message;
            dispatch({ message, type: GET_MY_PRODUCT_FAILED }); 
        });
    }
```

I've check the token in my phone and also trying to make many request using postman. So I don't think it's server side problem.

I'm using Laravel and using laravel passport for API authentication. I not sure why this happen if I continue to access many time, any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE :: I'm trying to capture whether the http request has the token from this [link](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/capturing_http_requests), and I don't get the problem anymore.

Comment: You were able to solve your issus? because I have the same error, I always have a 401 answer. I use Laravel backend. I made a post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54431720/how-add-in-the-header-the-authorization-for-method-fetch-in-react-native-backe

Answer (score 2):

It's a healthy mechanism for token expire. Maybe you have your token `(access_token)` for 5 minutes, then the token expired, you should use `refresh_token` to regain another new token `(access_token)`.

For code explanation:

```
async function fetchService(url) {
  const reqSetting = {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${Auth.access_token}`,
    },
  };
  const prevRequest = { url, reqSetting };
  const resp = await fetch(url, reqSetting);
  if (!resp.ok) {
    const error = new Error(resp.statusText || 'Request Failed!');
    if (resp.status === 401 || resp.status === 400) {
      const responseClone = resp.clone();
      const errorInfo = await resp.json();
      if (errorInfo.error == 'invalid_token') {
        // console.log('Token Expired', errorInfo);
        try {
          await refreshToken();
          const response = await fetchService(prevRequest.url);
          return response;
        } catch (err) {
          // handle why not refresh a new token
        }
      }
      return responseClone;
    }
    error.errorUrl = url;
    error.code = resp.status;
    throw error;
  }
  return resp;
}
```

Where the refresh token function is :

```
async function refreshToken() {
  const url = 'https://example.com/oauth/token';
  const data = {
    grant_type: 'refresh_token',
    refresh_token: Auth.refresh_token,
  };
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url, data);
    const data = res.json();
    Auth.access_token = data.access_token;
    Auth.refresh_token = data.refresh_token;
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

This `fetchService` will automatic regain a new token if old expired and then handle old request.

PS.
If you have multiple requests same time, the `fetchService` will need a little optimization. You'd better choose another regain token strategy like [saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga).