# How add in the Header the Authorization for method fetch in React Native? (backend Laravel)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-native, cors

I'm developing an application in `React Native` with a backend in `Laravel 5.6`. On the React Native side I have a problem to send `Authorization` in the header

To solve this problem I tried this solutions like:

- Set up `CORS` ([package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)) on the backend side and add the `mode: "cors"`and `mode: "no-cors"`  option in React Native
- Add in React Native the `credentials: 'include'` Option in fetch method

none of these solutions works. :s

React Native

Output error

```
statusCode 401
data Object {
   "message": "Unauthenticated.",
}
```

fetch method

```
export default  async ()=> {
    const access_token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN);
    const token_type = await AsyncStorage.getItem(TOKEN_TYPE);
    console.log(URL_LOGOUT);
    console.log(access_token);
    console.log(token_type.concat(' ', access_token));
    return fetch(URL_LOGOUT,{
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': token_type.concat(' ', access_token)
        },
    })
        .then(processResponse)
        .then(res => {
            const { statusCode, data } = res;
            console.log("statusCode",statusCode);
            console.log("data",data);
        })
        .catch( (error) =>{
            console.log(error)
        });
}
function processResponse(response) {
    const statusCode = response.status;
    const data = response.json();
    return Promise.all([statusCode, data]).then(res => ({
        statusCode: res[0],
        data: res[1]
    }));
}
```

Backend (Laravel)

cors.php

```
<?php

return [

    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,

];
```

api.php

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api','cors'])->group(function () {
...    
})
// I added the cors in the $routeMiddleware(Kernel)
```

I try with Postman, it works but not in the mobile application.

Comment: Compare your postman request with the request that is made with your browser (Using the network tab of your developer tools).

Comment: Try with Postman sending an OPTIONS request to the same URL, without the Authorization request header added, and notice what response you get.

Comment: Is this token JWT or something else? Also, what is `token_type`?

Comment: And then how are you validating tokens in Laravel? The message you got is due to invalid/improper token, not due to cors.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, I have code 200 but the action is not executed

Comment: @PredragBeocanin, `Authorization : Bearer cn389ncoiwuencr... `

Comment: @PredragBeocanin, yes it's true that the error comes from the token validation, it's because `header Authorization` is not sent in the request from react native and I don't know why

Comment: @FrankerZ, I just compared and on native react there is an request Option with `Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET` and then there is another request in `GET` with the right header parameter, but this one returns the error

Comment: @diego but the console log of the token just before fetch, shows the correct token?

Comment: @PredragBeocanin, Yes, the token is correct. but I don't know why React Native sends an Option request and after the request I want

Comment: That’s how it works, but it shouldn’t be a problem. And then how do you get the token laravel side?

Comment: We can jump on chat real quick if you want to resolve this now. Theres a bunch of stuff I could ask before we arrive anywhere

Comment: @PredragBeocanin, Yes, we can but how do you chat on stackoverflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187570/discussion-between-predrag-beocanin-and-diego).